# Exchange 2010 and user disabled

Tags: exchange-2010

In a default Exchange 2010 installation when a user account is disabled there is an automatism, in exchange, that delete or disconnect the mailbox associated to the user?

If yes, how this behaviour can be modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either disable a mailbox, which will disconnect the mailbox and leave the AD user enabled, or you can delete a mailbox, which will disconnect the mailbox and disable the AD user. In either case, disconnected mailboxes are cleaned up (removed) after 30 days by default. You can check your actual mailbox retention setting by running:

```
Get-MailboxDatabase | ft Name, MailboxRetention -a
```

Comment: Thank for the answer, what I'm asking here is if a disabled user via ADUC mantain his mailbox associated or exchange by default after some time delete it? And if yes, how to change this behaviour! Thank again

Comment: I misunderstood. You should see the link that TheCleaner posted above.